# Trying to initialize a list with values but not working when I use a variable to create the size

Tags: c++

This is my second time using C++ and I'm trying to port some Java code I made but am having trouble understanding some behavior. I have a list of data and want to create another list of the same size but the values are default to zero(in Java I use `Arrays.fill(list, 0);` after creating it). When I try to do something similar in C++ I get `variable-sized object 'list1' may not be initialized`

Here's a code to better example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp> // for 'operator+=()'

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    vector<short> data;
    data += -40, -30,-10, 20, 50;

    //int coeff [data.size()];
    cout << "data array size is " << data.size() << endl;
    short list1 [data.size()] = {0}; //does not work
    for (int i =0; i<data.size(); i++) {
        cout << "data is " << list1[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "********** try 2 **************" << endl;
    //this works if I use a actual number to create the list but I want to declare it at runtime
    short list2 [5] = {0};
    for (int ii=0;ii<5;ii++) {
        cout << "data is " << list2[ii] << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Like I mentioned, I'm completely green when I comes to C++ (I have read a book and done a few tutorials) so I may be doing something completely wrong.  In the event I cannot do this at runtime and only at compile time, is there something else I can use to get the same result?

Comment: This is what `std::vector<>` is for -- you're _already_ using it for `data`, just use it for `list1` as well.

Comment: @ildjarn I thought vector was for variable size lists? What if I want to create a fixed length list?

Comment: How is `short list1 [data.size()]` not an attempt at a variable size list??

Comment: @ildjarn sorry, I meant a list that doesn't change in size. vector's size seems to be able to change after creation, but is it still recommended to use it if the size of the list remains the same for its life(only the content inside changes). Sorry if this is totally wrong, I'm trying to understand how it works.

Comment: @Lostsoul:  Yes -- `vector`s are recommended even for collections that will never change size once you've initially populated them.

Comment: @JohnDibling sorry about that I didn't know.  I remember reading somewhere in the Java world that using lists(int[]) were much better performing than arraylists, so I was trying to copy that.  I'm starting to see C/C++ is a different beast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

c++ does not have dynamically sized arrays, so this is illegal:

```
short list1 [data.size()];
```

but you can use a vector:

```
std::vector<short> list1(data.size(),0);
```

That creates a vector of the same length as `data`, full of zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array whose size is determined at runtime, you'll have to allocate it.

```
short * list1 = new short[data.size()];
//do stuff
delete [] list1; //we don't want to leak
```

You typically want to avoid naked pointers whenever possible, so the cleaner solution is what juanchopanza suggested and try to use std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `Arrays.fill(list, 0);` for a C++ vector looks like `std::fill(list.begin(), list.end(), 0);`

You can also simply declare a `std::vector<short> list1(data.size());` to create it with zero initialized values or with a specific value `std::vector<short> list1(data.size(), 0);`